# How to check if string contains something else than numbers

Tags: java

How can I check if string contains something else than numbers?
I mean something like:

```java
String argsstring = args[0].toString();
if(argsstring.Contains NUMBER == false)
{
    Bukkit.shutdown
}
```

Comment: `s.matches("\\D+"); // No numbers present`

Comment: not so clear - "contains something else than numbers" is not same meaning as posted code `contains NUMBER` || `string.matches("\\d*")` will result in `false` if "string contains something else than numbers"; code from previous comment will result in `false` if "Contains NUMBER" (at least one number)

Comment: Best to use the term 'digit' when talking about individual characters. 12321 is one number, or five digits.

Comment: @ArfurNarf, 0 through 9 are numbers, also, though.

Comment: 'A' is both a letter and a word, but one of those terms is more appropriate in context.

Comment: @ArfurNarf, what context?  They are talking about numbers within a text.  When would 0 through 9 not be considered?

Comment: 123.456 is a number; it contains a non-digit.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate the characters within *argsstring*, and test the value against a *String* of each digit.

```java
String digits = "1234567890";
boolean nonDigitFound = false;
for (char character : argsstring.toCharArray()) {
    if (!digits.contains(String.valueOf(character))) {
        nonDigitFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex should have been used

Comment: @rgnt, it's just a solution.